# is there a python equivalent of C IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED macro?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, gdb, gdb-python

I am trying to write some gdb scripts with python.

There is a version neutral C definition of an ip address as follows :

```
typedef struct ip_addr {
    union {
        struct in6_addr v6;
        struct {
            uint32_t v4_unused[2];
            uint32_t v4_marker;
            uint32_t v4;
        };
    };
#define v6_addr v6.s6_addr
} ip_addr_t;
```

In C, one can use a following macro to check if a given IP address is v4 or v6 :

netinet/in.h

```
# define IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED(a) \
  (__extension__                                  \
   ({ const struct in6_addr *__a = (const struct in6_addr *) (a);         \
      __a->__in6_u.__u6_addr32[0] == 0                        \
      && __a->__in6_u.__u6_addr32[1] == 0                     \
      && __a->__in6_u.__u6_addr32[2] == htonl (0xffff); }))
```

for the gdb script i am trying to do something similar to above macro:

python printers for the ipaddress :

```
def ip_to_string(ip, isV4):
    if isv4 == 1:
        return ipv4_to_string(ip)
    else:
        return ipv6_to_string(ip)

def ip4_to_string(ip):
    return socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET, struct.pack("=L", int(ip)))

def ipv6_to_string(ip):
    return socket.inet_ntop(socket.AF_INET6, socket.inet_pton(socket.AF_INET6, ip.v6_addr))
```

The Tuple printer has the following invocation :

```
   def to_string(self):
        src_ip = ip_to_string(self.val["src_ipx_addr"])
        dst_ip = ip_to_string(self.val["dst_ipx_addr"])
```

Any easier way i can identify if the C struct *ip_addr_t* is a v4 or v6 address in python ?

TIA.